# Creating and calling custom exceptions

Tags: java, exception

I am writting a HighLow game that generates a random number then asks the user to guess what it is. The input will then get a response of either "too high," "too low," or "Correct." I have the game made fine but the issue is that the :too high," "too low," and "correct" responses have to be using custom exception classes. I have created the custom exception classes but I am not sure how to get the program to trow the exception (any help is greatly apperciated). I tried replacing my original code with the following but it does not even come close to working:

```
if (guess < number) { 
throw TooLowException;   
} else if (guess > number) {
throw TooHighException;    
} else {
throw CorrectException;
}
```

Original Code:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class HelloWorld {

    public class TooHighException extends Exception {
    }

    public class TooLowException extends Exception {
    }

    public class CorrectException extends Exception {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random random = new Random();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number = random.nextInt(100);
        int guess = -1;
        while (guess != number) {
            System.out.print("Enter your guess: ");
            guess = scanner.nextInt();
            if (guess < number) {
                System.out.println("Too low, guess again");
            }
            else if (guess > number) {
                System.out.println("Too high, guess again");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Correct, the random number was " + number);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It should be: `throw new TooLowException();` But generally speaking, you shouldn't be using Exceptions for controlflow. They are expensive.

Comment: Please Format your code proberly

Comment: Exceptions should be exceptional and are only needed when you want to break the normal flow of execution. I assume this is just an exercise but returning an Enum values would be more appropriate.

Comment: My mind just kind of jams up on throwing a `CorrectException`. Huh? Aside from what others have said, when you extend `Exception` you create a "checked" exception. When you extend `RuntimeException` you create an "unchecked" exception. Look those terms up. You also nested your exception definitions, `CorrectException` [sic] inside `TooLowException` inside `TooHighException`, which is wrong. It also imposes changes on how you refer to them. Remember that to create any object from a class, you need `new` or an equivalent means (reflection, deserialization) to obtain the object.

Comment: I know exceptions should not be used for this but it is what the professor has asked us to do.Per the program requirmements: "Program generates tooHigh, tooLow or correct exceptions.  You must write custom exception classes for each of these situation (For example: TooHigh.java, TooLow.java)"

Comment: This is one of the scariest tasks I've ever heard of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code to make your idea working:

```
class TooHighException extends Exception {
}


class TooLowException extends Exception {
}


class CorrectException extends Exception {
}

public class HelloWorld {

public void main(String[] args) throws TooLowException, TooHighException, CorrectException {

    Random random = new Random();
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int number = random.nextInt(100);
    int guess = -1;
    while (guess != number) {
        System.out.print("Enter your guess: ");
        guess = scanner.nextInt();
        if (guess < number) {
            throw new TooLowException();
        } else if (guess > number) {
            throw new TooHighException();
        } else {
            throw new CorrectException();
        }
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The Exceptions are classes, and you have to create instances of them to throw, like this:

```
if (guess < number) { 
    throw new TooLowException();   
} else if (guess > number) {
    throw new TooHighException();
} else {
    throw new CorrectException();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Exceptions for control flow. It's a guessing game and none of the three possibilities is an exception to it which becomes very clear after thinking a moment about this class name: `CorrectException`.

Comment: I understand that this is not the desired way to do it, however it is what the exercise has asked for. The last bit, about making an exception class for a correct response makes no sense at all, but I am not the professor. That is what she asked for. Per the program requirmements: "Program generates tooHigh, tooLow or correct exceptions.  You must write custom exception classes for each of these situation (For example: TooHigh.java, TooLow.java)"